# Attempting to search a MySQL database in PHP with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, search, pdo

I am attempting to find results that resemble queries in a search for example, when someone searches "tes" I want "Test McTestFace" to come up.

I have attempted to use both LIKE and MATCH AGAINST methods and, neither seem to work. When using MATCH AGAINST, nothing comes up whereas when using LIKE, only direct matches come up.

My code for MATCH AGAINST:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST (:query)");
    $query->execute(array('query' => $_POST['query']));
    $result = $query->fetch();
}
print_r($result);
```

My code for LIKE:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name LIKE :query");
    $query->execute(array('query' => $_POST['query']));
    $result = $query->fetch();
}
print_r($result);
```

Sorry and thank you.

Comment: I fail to understand exactly what it is you want to achieve. Would you consider trying to pose a concise question?

Comment: @Bex Sorry that you don't find it concise enough, (whilst it has been answered now) I was trying to ask how to use the LIKE (or MATCH AGAINST) value for MySQL queries correctly. For specific reasoning, I am attempting to make a simple search form that allows one to enter a close string and receive a list or users that match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using `LIKE` you need to wrap the query with the wildcard `%` to make it work.

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html):

> With LIKE you can use the following two wildcard characters in the pattern:
>
> % matches any number of characters, even zero characters.
>
> _ matches exactly one character.

i.e.

```
$query->execute(array('query' => '%' . $_POST['query'] . '%'));
```

Comment: Is it possible to sort based on how similar results are?

Comment: Probably the simplest way would be to `ORDER BY name`

Answer (score 1):

To match against wildcards, you need to use `'%'.$_POST['query'].'%'`. (for LIKE).

Comment: Give it to the other one, it's more complete, hence better.